# Can I use "this" in this case?

Tags: demonstrative-pronouns

[image]

As you see, it's not a strawberry, it's just a flower pot.

1. This strawberry is fake.
2. This strawberry isn't real.

Are these sentences correct?

I'm wondering after seeing this title on a [YouTube video](https://youtu.be/liV0NxDzV68?feature=shared)

> Is This Food Real Or Fake?

Comment: You would use 'this strawberry' about... a strawberry. A real one. You could use scare quotes, maybe.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Then, can I just say "a strawberry is fake"?

Comment: It is not a strawberry. It's a vase or flower pot made to look like a strawberry.

Comment: The idea of something *looking real* and instead being fake is a trend, I haven't seen the video but I'm guessing that the presenters are talking about cakes looking like pieces of fruit, or other food staples etc. You have to guess if the food you are seeing is real or a just a cake i.e. "fake"

Comment: The photo example is not a good one, anyone who thinks that one of the vases could be an edible strawberry needs their eyes testing. It's obvious that it's a representation of the fruit in clay/ceramic form. You could say something like: This is real but *that* is fake (or vice versa)

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Then, it's just an error in a casual conversation? But still meaningful?

Comment: @Mari-LouA Is it just because English is natural language? It's not logical but meaningful though.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Agreed, but I had a quick scan through the video and they are showing groups of 4 close-up images of what appears to be food, but when they pan back one of the items is something different. For example, 3 images of bacon and one of wood planks with a bacon-like grain pattern. Not at all like the strawberry vases.

Comment: My wife's friend has a 'plushie' aubergine toy. With two eyes and a bow-tie. He's called Gene. They would both be so annoyed if someone called him a 'fake'.

Comment: I fear that these comments have strayed away from the OP's question and into the merits of the image. It may not be a good example, but the two sentences are grammatically correct.

Comment: Calling it "this strawberry" seems fine. You'd say "this bear" with a toy bear or a model of a bear.

Comment: _Can I just say "a strawberry is fake"?_ No, that would mean that some random strawberry was an artificial one. _This_ is fine to mean  _the one in the picture I'm showing you_.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, it's odd that the question is about the word "this." There's no reason not to use "this"; it just means "the object at hand." I would suggest that your real question is whether it's okay to call it a *strawberry*. And I would say that it's okay, for several reasons:

- We often refer to representations by using the same word as the thing they represent. If we lined up several flowerpots of various designs, and said "put it in the strawberry," our meaning would be clear. Technically, we do this every time we deal with images. There is not even a flowerpot *on* my screen right now; rather, there is a pattern of glowing pixels that puts me in mind of a flowerpot which puts me in mind of a strawberry. This is part of the idea behind Magritte's painting [*La Trahison des Images*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Treachery_of_Images), in which he puts a picture of a tobacco pipe and the caption *Ceci n'est pas une pipe*—"This is not a pipe"—because, well, no, it's not a pipe, it's a painting of one. And yet he calls attention to the fact that we *do* often talk in exactly this way.
- I think it's also OK because the sentence "changes our perception." The representation of a strawberry is so good that at first glance I did think it was one. When we're describing a change (in this case, a change in our perception), it's okay to use a construction that describes both the "before" and "after" situation in their own terms. For instance, we might say "the caterpillar turned into a butterfly," even though, afterwards, there is no "the caterpillar" anymore. Similarly, if the heroes of *Scooby-Doo* reveal that the supposed ghost was really a villain in a bedsheet, they might say "The ghost was just Old Man Jenner all along!" and we wouldn't fault them for using "the ghost" when in fact there was not one. This sentence uses the language of their *initial perception* ("the ghost") as well as their changed perception. So I think it's okay to say "this strawberry," just as the show *Is it Cake* might say something like "Is this handbag actually a cake?" I would say that you *could* use scare quotes ("This 'strawberry' is fake") if you *wish*, but you don't have to.

Answer (score -1):

No, you have to use quotation marks:

This 'strawberry' is fake.

Comment: That would be one way of indicating that it wasn't a real strawberry.