Can I call a glass bottle (is in the shape of a gourd) a glass gourd?
When we say "he drank water from a gourd", it usually means he drank water from a bottle made out of a real gourd.
Now we have a glass bottle that is in the shape of a gourd.
Can I call the below bottle a glass gourd?
 (source)
Someone says it is a gourd-shaped bottle.
Also "a glug bottle" also has its middle smaller than the top and the bottom.

This has quite a lot in common with https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/344655/138287 : We can speak of representations of a thing as that thing. That is, if I had a glass sculpture of an apple, that clearly meant to depict an apple, I might call it "a glass apple." But if it's just vaguely apple-shaped, I would not. To my mind, gourds are variable enough and this bottle is abstract enough that "glass gourd" doesn't work here.

I think  A gourd-shaped bottle is best way of describing it. Glug bottles are specially designed to make noises when pouring.  Steve Mould on YouTube has an excellent video explaining how they work https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2IKZIWVHXvo

Interestingly, every single one of the 10 result in the first page returned by a Google Books search for a gourd bottle is a dictionary definition (mostly, intended for non-native Anglophones). Which should tell you that Anglophones don't use the word gourd very often, so they wouldn't necessarily be able to guess what shape "a gourd bottle" should be. Personally, I wouldn't have known it meant a "double-necked" bottle if it weren't for the above picture.

@FumbleFingers, double-necked bottle might look like this https://www.webpackaging.com/Up/Comp/4004/11624938/11812549-EDNJZBSW/i/prev/1516589902673621%20(1).jpg

@Tom: Whatever - like I said, Anglophones don't use "gourd" much, so gourd (shaped) bottle isn't an immediately accessible term. When I googled gourd bottle, all i got was pictures of gourds, but hourglass (shaped) bottle gets plenty of pictures like yours.

No. I'm pretty sure. Not in the US or UK at least.
Looking up "glass gourd" on Google I find mostly gourd-shaped glass decorations and things that seem to be drawing from foreign languages (like argentinian maté cups, or something that looks suspiciously like what French would call "une gourde" that has nothing to do with the vegetable).
Which isn't to say it's completely impossible but I would say the only context where you'd say "I drank out of the glass gourd" and it would make sense is if you're talking with someone else who knows exactly what gourd-shaped glass bottle you're talking about and you're kind of winking at each other about it. Like if you had a cat-shaped bottle and said "I drank out of the cat": you'd both know what you mean but it's not a turn of phrase that's a general part of the language.
Basically "bottle" isn't a shape per se, it's a tool. Even if the tool is gourd-shaped, it's a bottle. If you don't call it a bottle then you're suggesting it's not that tool (for example it's decorative, or it's being used in an ad-hoc way for that tool's purpose but you're mostly focusing on its non-tool nature)

A "glass gourd" would imply to me something specifically designed and decorated to look like a gourd, like a figurine of a glass pumpkin. What you have depicted is not a gourd or intended to represent a gourd. It is merely gourd-shaped, so I would not refer to it as a glass gourd. It might be understood in a figurative sense, but I agree that referring to it as a gourd-shaped bottle is a better description.
